# How to make Fluro defined route parameters OPTIONAL in flutter?

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-web

I have defined this route using Fluro.
`exchange/:pair`

There is a problem! I want `:pair` to be optional. If client types `https://host:port/exchange/BNB_BTC` everything goes fine. but assume the user is looking for `https://host:port/exchange` and he confronts with 404 error cause there is no such route/path.